# Will legacy "Improved Warzone Experience" affect the CXP I get from warzones?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Under Legacy, I have the perks for "Improved Warzone Experience" unlocked, levels 1 to 5. This essentially improves the XP I used to get when playing warzones, pre level 50 (yes - I've recently returned hehe).

[image]

So the question is; will this also improve my Command Experience (CXP) I get for playing warzones, now that I'm level 70?

Comment: I'd _highly_ doubt it, but can't confirm at the moment.